# Testify About/To

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I have a question about the usage of "*testify about*" and "*testify to*".  Suppose the setting is a court trial for a burglary case and John is on the witness stand:

> 1. John *testified* ***about*** Peter's role in the burglary.
> 2. John *testified* ***to*** Peter's role in the burglary.

How is "*about*" and "*to*" different?

Comment: I'd actually say that John testified *about* Peter's role. He testified *to* the judge, and in his testament he *attested to* Peter's role in the burglary.

Comment: "To testify to" is to swear in support of a particular allegation or claim; to "testify about" is to offer evidence in general.  "He claims to have been at home at the time of the murder. Can you testify to that?"  "Can you testify about the role he played in the scam?"

Comment: TRomano is correct. The scenario in your example probably wouldn't happen in court as in your sentences. For example, the psychologist for the defence would testify about antisocial personality disorder. However, he would testify to Peter having this diagnosis and how it contributed to his behavior and the burglary. On the other hand, in general usage, there is scarcely a difference other than what is required by grammar and semantics. Other than that, in court, you are likely to see "for" or "against" after some derivation of testify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "testify about" a person's actions is to relate details of the actions. To "testify to" a person's actions is to confirm that the person committed the actions, without necessarily providing details. If asked, "Did Peter rob the store?", a response of "Yes, he did" is to testify to his having robbed the store. Granted, adding details is normal, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

The meanings are very similar, but if you testify *about* the crime then you'd give a lot of general information that might be of help to the prosecutors. On the other hand if you testify *to* the crime then you have concrete information that will provide **strong and direct** evidence against Peter.

When the verb **testify** is paired with the preposition **to**, you're specifically saying *what* John is testifying about. He is giving evidence against Peter's role, that's it. But if John is testifying **about** Peter's role, then he could be testifying against anything that's related to it.